# How to quickly find file in the workspace/switch between buffers/etc. in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, textmate, fuzzy-search, ido-mode, fuzzyfinder

I am looking for something like Textmate's fuzzy search on Command-T, [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) in Vim, or [Ido](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) in Emacs. Does it exist? If no, how do you prefer to do it?

Comment: I am still interested in a real fuzzy search, so if i want to search for "user_helper.rb" I just want to write "ushlrb". Eclipse forces you to use patterns, in this case "*us*rb". Anyone knows a plugin for eclipse for a real fuzzy search?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>  will search each for any "Resource" (file), anywhere in your project

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>  will search for a specific open file (ie. your buffers)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp/PageDown</kbd> will navigate to the next/previous open buffer

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd> will navigate backward/forward in your browsing history

(eg. if you went from tab 1 to tab 5 to tab 2 and then hit <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+Left</kbd>, you'd go back to tab 5; you could then hit <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+Left</kbd> to go back to tab 1, or ...+Right to go back to tab 2)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+3` gives contextual text search across editors, commands and preferences.  I only recently discovered this one - not sure if it was a new feature with Eclipse 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GotoFile plugin](https://github.com/adelarsq/eclipse-gotofile-plugin-kai). Type Ctrl+Alt+N to use. Works with Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 0):

[`Ctrl+Shift+R` works for files, `Ctrl+Shift+T` for types.](http://eclipsetips.wordpress.com/2007/12/07/fuzzy-search/) Still looking for an answer for buffers.

Comment: None of these are true "fuzzy" searches. They all require you to enter the beginning of the file name.